# OpenLiteSpeed on RHEL8.5

Tags: redhat, rhel8, litespeed

I'm using EC2 with RHEL8.5 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.5 (Ootpa)). I wanted to install OpenLiteSpeed on that instance. my Question, Does OpenLiteSpeed support with RHEL8? If I don't wrong, centos and RHEL is on same umbrella, Red Hat. So why I cannot install OpenLiteSpeed using centos RPM in my RHEL 8.5?

From this [documents](https://docs.openlitespeed.org), its supported Centos 8 so I think its supported as well. But when I trying to

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://rpms.litespeedtech.com/centos/litespeed-repo-1.1-1.el8.noarch.rpm
```

than the error appears

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    centos-release >= 5 is needed by litespeed-repo-1.2-1.el8.noarch
```

I'm trying to dig on Google, I found this [article](https://www.techsupportpk.com/2019/12/how-to-install-openlitespeed-web-server-centos-8-rhel-8.html) and this [article](https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-openlitespeed-webserver-centos-8-rhel-8/). Trying to follow up and with no luck. Same error as above.

I have trying to use

```
yum clean metadata
```

also with no luck.

Does anyone have experience to install OpenLiteSpeed on RHEL8.5?

Answer (score 0):

That is a package no one tested on RHEL. It would have worked except for the dependency.

Have the maintainers change that to  `redhat-release`.  `centos-release` provides `redhat-release` for compatibility.

To work around the problem, skip the repo package. The gpg key and repo files are adjacent there, download and install them to `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/` and `/etc/yum.repos.d/` respectively.

Comment: I have trying to skip the repo package by download the RPM file to yum.repos.d and trying to install it manually by comment `rpm -ivh` or `yum localinstall` but still no luck with same error `centos-release >= 5 is needed by litespeed-repo-1.2-1.el8.noarch`.